# How to hide a grid column when a toggle button is checked in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, grid

On the right side of my Form I have a grid with two on columns,the right column is "45" in width and the left one named "LeftColumn" is set as "Auto" for width.
I would like to use checked and unchecked events of a toggle button named "Togglebtn" to show and hide that "LeftColumn"

Comment: A code sample would help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to your ColumnDefinition

`<ColumnDefinition x:Name="ExchangeColumn" Width="0" />`

`<Button Clicked="OnExpandExchange" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>`

And use the following methods

```
        private void OnExpandExchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ExchangeColumn.Width.Value == 0)
        {
            GetExpandAnimation().Commit(this, ExpandAnimationName, 16,
                100,
                Easing.CubicIn,
                null, () => false);
        }
        else
        {
            GetCollapseAnimation().Commit(this, CollapssAnimationName, 16,
                100,
                Easing.CubicInOut,
                null, () => false);
        }
    }

    private Animation GetExpandAnimation()
    {
        return new Animation
        {
            {0, 1, new Animation(v => ExchangeColumn.Width= v, 0, 45)}
        };
    }

    private Animation GetCollapseAnimation()
    {
        return new Animation
        {
            {0, 1, new Animation(v => ExchangeColumn.Width = v, 45, 0)}
        };
    }
```